# IEnumerable to array of T[]

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Perhaps the question title is incorrect. I have the following variables

```
IEnumerable x = // some IEnumerable
System.Type y = // some type
```

**How can iterate over x in order to generate an array with items of type y?**

When I look into the internet I found:

```
public T[] PerformQuery<T>(IEnumerable q)
{                         
        T[] array = q.Cast<T>().ToArray();
        return array;
}
```

Note I cannot call that method PerformQuery becuase `y` is of type `System.Type` in other words calling it as `PerformQuery<typeof(y)>(x);` or `PerformQuery<y>(x);` will give me a compiler error.

---

### edit

Here is the reason why I have that problem. I have web service where I post to it two things. The type of table I will like to query (example typeof(Customer)), and the actual string query example "Select * from customers"

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // code to deserialize posted data
        Type table = // implement that here
        String query = // the query that was posted

        // note DB is of type DbContext
        IEnumerable q = Db.Database.SqlQuery(table, query );

        // here I will like to cast q to an array of items of type table!
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Unless you have a known compile-time type, this isn't going to be all that useful (unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Expression Trees:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Array ToArray(this IEnumerable source, Type type)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable), "source");
        var cast = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Cast", new[] { type }, param);
        var toArray = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "ToArray", new[] { type }, cast);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable, Array>>(toArray, param).Compile();

        return lambda(source);
    }
}
```

It generates `x => x.Cast<Type>().ToArray()` for you, with `Type` known at runtime.

Usage:

```
IEnumerable input = Enumerable.Repeat("test", 10);
Type type = typeof(string);

Array result = input.ToArray(type);
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer? the `Array result` is still of unknown type, isn't it? looks like you're overcomplicating it with no extra benefit

Comment: +1 thanks a lot. How can I get the inner array of System.Array so that I return an object of type `dynamic[]` instead of `System.Array`

Comment: You can just cast it to `dynamic[]`: `(dynamic[])result`

Answer (score 5):

```
var ObjectsOfType_y = x.OfType<object>().Where(x => x.GetType() == y);
```

Notice that this will return an `IEnumerable<object>`, though. There's no way around that because the type that `y` (Type) represents is unknown at compile time.

Comment: How did `IEnumerable<object>` become an answer for *I need T[]* question?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, IENumerable contains only one type. If I understand what you're trying to do, IENumerable already only contains only objects of type y. If y needs to change, you can write an extension method:

```
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        int length = System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(source);
        T[] newArray = new T[length];
        int i = 0;
        foreach(T item in source)
        {
            newArray[i] = item;
        }
        return newArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot simpler if you use C#'s dynamic dispatch, using the `dynamic` keyword. You dont even need fancy methods or, even the `Type` you have. You can directly use your method. So if you have

```
public T[] PerformQuery<T>(IEnumerable<T> q)
{                         
        T[] array = q.ToArray();
        return array;
}
```

Just call

```
IEnumerable x = // some IEnumerable
dynamic y = x;
IEnumerable z = PerformQuery(y);
```